# Много ли пользователей посещают веб сайты без JS в браузере?

Tags: javascript, бот, спам

Выявляю спам-ботов, заполняющих форму на сайте, с помощью JS - если бот не использует JS то он не сможет отправить данные из формы. Интересует каков шанс что попадется такой пользователь без JS, которому тоже не удастся форму заполнить? И дополнительный вопрос - подавляющее ли большинство спам-ботов, рассылающих спам через формы на сайтах, не используют JS?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111615/discussion-between-andreymal-and-molof).

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужно защититься от ботов в какой-то степени то можно обмануть их сделав поле `display:none` и если оно заполнено значит у тебя бот на сайте. 99% браузеров поддерживают JS, если у пользователя не работает JS, то он отключил его осознанно.

Насчет использования JS ботами, то все зависит от бота.

Comment: От многих ли ботов поможет атрибут display:none? Бот ведь может просто игнорировать поля с таким атрибутом.

Comment: поэтому я и написал " в какой-то степени "